# Grep regex inside bash

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I need to use a regular expression in `grep` inside a bash script where I am trying to find the following occurrences inside a file:

`foo,`
`foo ,`
`foo)`
`foo )`

In the file, there are multiple occurrences of this word in other patterns that I want to ignore, like:

`foo"`
`foo.`
etc

Right now I am doing individual grep for each, but I want to use a single expression for all of these. I tried `'foo.,'` and `'foo.)'`, but I still need 2 expressions and it (obviously) gives me matches with any character at the place of `.` which I don't want. What can I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to try & match comma, space, `(`, `)` etc.

Just use `foo` with word boundaries:

```
grep '\<foo\>' file
```

To specifically match those 4 strings:

```
egrep '\<foo ?[,)]' file
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I phrased my question wrong. In a file, I want to find the four cases that I mentioned, and not just the word in the four cases !

Comment: @rgamber Please clarify: are there other instances of `foo` (not followed by `,`, space, `(` or `)`) that you would like to avoid matching?

Comment: Yes, there are. I'll update the question to say that.

Comment: It works fine when I run it directly in the terminal. When I use it in the bash script, that is when I get the error.

Comment: Can you post your BASH script so that I can investigate.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40784/discussion-between-rgamber-and-anubhava)

Comment: Sorry I just got back. Are you still having problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -e 'foo \?[,)]' file_to_check
```

You probably want the word boundary answer though.